# How to remove CheckBox icon of only the Header row for DataTable in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a DataTable and want to keep the automatically generated checkbox column that indicates which row is currently selected. My implementation only allows a single row to be selected at once, so I want to get rid of the automatically generated checkbox in the header row that causes all rows to be selected at once. I tried setting onSelectAll to null, but that did not hide the checkbox. Setting onSelectAll: (b) {} disables the functionality but does not hide the checkbox.

Here is the code for the function I'm using to generate the table:

```
Widget _itemTable(List data) {
  if(data.length == 0) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      child: Text("No data found")
    );
  }

  var headers = data[0].keys;

  List<DataRow> rows = [];

  int selectedIndex = 1;
  int i = 0;

  data.forEach(
    (item) {
      rows.add(
        DataRow(
          selected: selectedIndex == i,
          onSelectChanged: (selected) {
            if (selected ?? false) {
              print(item);
              selectedIndex = i;
            }
          },
          cells: 
            headers.map<DataCell>(
              (String hdr) => DataCell(Text(item[hdr].toString()))
            ).toList()
        )
      );
      i++;
    }
  );
  
  return Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: DataTable(
        onSelectAll: (b) {},
        columns: ["id", "category", "subject", "details"].map<DataColumn>((h) => DataColumn(label: Text(h))).toList(),
        rows: rows
      )
    )
  );
}
```

The data List is just a list of objects with keys matching the headers listed in the columns of the DataTable

Comment: can you include `data` that you are passing on `_itemTable()`?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I edited the question, the data is just a list of objects with keys matching the values listed in the columns of the DataTable